# installing a virtual machine + ubuntu on a macbook air m1

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtual-machine

for the last 3 days i've  been struggling to run ubuntu on my macbook m1, i tried 3 different virtual machines ( oracle virtual box, Utm and parallel )
oracle virtualbox didn't even run ubuntu it crashes after the installation is complete even though i chose "​Developer preview for macOS / Arm64 (M1/M2) hosts"
Utm : the same thing
parallel it worked i installed everything and ubuntu is working but when i try to change the keyboard from qwerty to azerty by going to the setting then region then install new language it show "“failed to download package files”" so i'm really lost and don't know what to do plus. i have an exam in august about linux and c programming so that's why im a bit stressed, if someone knows what to do please help me thank you so much in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not sure what your issue is, since there's not enough info, but try downloading for mac here, https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads, then *follow directions* here: https://brb.nci.nih.gov/seqtools/installUbuntu.html . Last time I installed VBox, I was pleasantly surprised how quickly it installed, and how quickly it created a new VM (though the VM uses about 40 GB to save).

Comment: Thank you so much for you me help I’m sorry if wasn’t clear in my last post, i installed UTM and it worked not sure how but it worked haha i just followed some YouTube videos, but for the oracle virtual box it didn’t work not sure why after some research i found out that lots of people had the same issue as me, after installation the vm works perfectly but once you download Ubuntu and you try to run it In vm it crashes. So if virtual box doesn’t work i recommend that you try another virtual machine ( my advice for anyone that’s facing the same problem as me ) have a good day And happy coding

Comment: Which file Ubuntu installer file did you download from Canonical for use with VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try VMware Fusion Player. I believe you can use this product for free after getting a free [Personal Use License](https://customerconnect.vmware.com/en/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal-13).

There is this VMware Knowledge Base Article: [The Unofficial Fusion 13 for Apple Silicon Companion Guide](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Documents/The-Unofficial-Fusion-13-for-Apple-Silicon-Companion-Guide/ta-p/2939907) which has this [link](https://communities.vmware.com/wbsdv95928/attachments/wbsdv95928/3006/558/39/Fusion%2013%20for%20Apple%20Silicon%20Companion%20v18.pdf) to download revision 18 (16-June-2023) of the PDF version of the actual guide.

This guide explains how to get Ubuntu running in VMware Fusion Player.